# Variable from if loop to other loop

Tags: c#, loops, variables, if-statement, foreach

I have two loops and i want to get value "statusP" to foreach loop.
How can I do it? 
Probably the solution is simple but I can not find it myself.

```
public void potwierdzWybor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string statusP = "";
        if (platnoscT.Checked == true)
        {
            statusP = "O";
            Label1.Text = statusP;
        }
        else if (platnoscP.Checked == true)
        {
            statusP = "P";
            Label1.Text = statusP;
        }
        else
        {
            Label1.Text = "Nothing choose";
        }

}
```

second loop where i want value statusP from if loop:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            var chk = (HtmlInputCheckBox)row.FindControl("checkboxID");
            var selectedRoomID = (Label)row.FindControl("Label2");
            var cenaPokoj = (Label)row.FindControl("LabelCena");

            if (chk.Checked && chk != null)
            {


                Label1.Text = cenaPokoj.Text;


                 String CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ConnectionString;
                 using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
                 {

                     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dodajRezerwacje", con);
                     cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dataStart",Convert.ToDateTime(CalendarStart.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString()));
                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dataStop", Convert.ToDateTime(CalendarStop.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString()));
                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cena", Convert.ToInt32(cenaPokoj.Text));
                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@statusPlat", platnosc);
                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_login", Session["LOGIN"].ToString());
                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_pokoj",Convert.ToInt32(selectedRoomID.Text));


                     SqlParameter outputParamater = new SqlParameter("@wiadomosc", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 250);
                     outputParamater.ParameterName = "@wiadomosc";
                     outputParamater.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
                     cmd.Parameters.Add(outputParamater);
                     con.Open();
                     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                     string msgRezerwacja = outputParamater.Value.ToString();
                     Label1.Text = msgRezerwacja;

                 }
            }
            else if (chk == null)
            {

                Label1.Text = "Wybierz pokój";

            }




        }
```

I want to pass this value to the stored procedure call.

Comment: `if` is not a looping construct. Sounds like you need to learn about variables scopes, class members, or method parameters.

Comment: You should reverse the order of these checks: `if (chk.Checked && chk != null)`. As it stands now, if `chk` is `null`, the first condition will throw a `NullReferenceException`, since the conditions are executed from left to right. Or, better yet, just switch the order of your `else if` and `if`: `if(chk == null) { Label1.Text = "Wybierz pokój"; } else if (chk.Checked) { … }`

Answer (score 0):

Your first method is not a foor loop like @BradleyDotNET said.

It's better to read more about [for (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/for)
and [foreach, in (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in) 
and [while (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/while) .
Now, for your main question : It's easy to do so by declaring the variable outside the button scope, to make it visible and usable from the whole class

then your first Method will be :

```
string statusP = ""; // will be seen in the whole class.

public void potwierdzWybor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (platnoscT.Checked == true)
        {
            statusP = "O";
            Label1.Text = statusP;
        }
        else if (platnoscP.Checked == true)
        {
            statusP = "P";
            Label1.Text = statusP;
        }
        else
        {
            Label1.Text = "Nothing choose";
        }

}
```